# Issue to open Web Browser and show web page from Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently developing an Web API programs with ASP.Net Core.
If someone calls a method from outside the Web API, it opens a specific web page(internal website).

When I run it from visual studio it works without errors, which occurs an error after I create a web site from IIS.

The below is my code.

```
                    Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe",
                        Arguments = "http://localhost:5005/Popup/myPopUp/Index?Id=" + rtnVal + " --kiosk",
                        UseShellExecute = true

                    });
```

**the below is the error I am getting**
Faulting application name: Chrome.exe, version: 98.0.4758.81, time stamp: 0x61f44457
Faulting module name: chrome_elf.dll, version: 98.0.4758.81, time stamp: 0x61f44457
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x0000000000032160
Faulting process id: 0x98b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d81a0c3774c3af
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\98.0.4758.81\chrome_elf.dll
Report Id: 8a41bdb3-7f86-4784-8af6-b7154bf5b7e7
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: You are trying to open a web browser on the server? I don't think that will work. You can open a new tab using javascript in the client - but only if the user allows it.

Comment: Thank you. How do I communicate the javascript from the controller of the web api?

Comment: Well you can return the URL from the WebAPI but you can't force the client to open a new tab.  I suppose you will just have to document to the developer of the client that they _should_ open this in a new tab. Course the user will be prompted if the URL is in a different domain that the API.

I don't really know what you are trying to do. You might think about asking a new question around that.

Comment: What do you plan to do with this data after you call an API? Return together with a specific web page or separately, and then open the specific web page you specify.